# Object is possibly 'undefined' after explicitly checking it's undefined

Tags: typescript

I'm having some issue with the following code:

```
const sentences: Record<string, string|undefined> = {
    // Empty here but receives properties eventually
};    

const reader = (id: string) => {
    if (sentences.a !== undefined) {
        sentences.a.split(' '); // Works
    }

    if (sentences[id] !== undefined) {
        sentences[id].split(' '); // Object possibly undefined
    }
}
```

I know that I could use `sentences[id]!` but I'm more curious to know why the second branch behaves in this way and if there's a way to get it to behave like the first without overusing `!`

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmYqOPCAuGAleoBOAJgDzR4CWYA5gDRxTlUA%20ArmAfAGYXwEB8MAXhgBvAFAwJMAPRSYAUQC2ABygBPGAAt4eeDABGzWDtRkAbmhhK8IJdqhkL8c0mYBDADbvVogL4BuSRhRUVBII3hXdjxBGAAKMgJMUgpKAEpBfjFAsg44hCQUNAA6VxgAQgEhVnYuMB50rMDJfOQwVAgSoogldzIoWIByGAHUgJkYAHUQPABrCHFJH2Ds3NiWwogAbQSAXXLKmGrObgIGhaa4RFb27YIdrp6%20weHR6VkJjXUwECgAfnOYEsfEA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't narrow down dynamically accessed properties. But what you can do is store the value into a variable, then it will get narrowed:

```
const sentence = sentences[id];
if (sentence !== undefined) {
    sentence.split(' ');
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmYqOPCAuGAleoBOAJgDzR4CWYA5gDRxTlUA+ArmAfAGYXwEB8MAXhgBvAFAwJMAPRSYAUQC2ABygBPGAAt4eeDABGzWDtRkAbmhhK8IJdqhkL8c0mYBDADbvVogL4BuSRhRUVBII3hXdjxBGAAKMgJMUgpKAEpBfjFAsg44hCQUNAA6VxgAQgEhVnYuMB50rMDJfOQwVAgSoogldzIoWIByGAHUgJkYAHUQPABrCHFJH2DA0Og4RFbUGJbCiABtBIBdPwWJHLyNwvLKmGrObgIG06adtvgunr7B4dHpWSnZvNAksfEA)

Answer (score 1):

For an explanation to this, you could easily do something like:

```
if (sentences[id] !== undefined) {
    id = "newId"; // <--- mutate id 
    sentences[id].split(' '); 
    // ^^^ This is a problem now. sentences[id] can be undefined
}
```

Comment: Yes I do agree but in the first case you can do `sentences.a = undefined` and then TS will correctly determine that `sentences.a` is undefined at the point of access. I am wondering why it doesn't just work in the second branch until `id` is mutated. I guess the real answer is that TS just doesn't support this